# Vector of strings works correctly before sorting, but afterwards it can't do anything

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector

I was working on a problem which required me to sort vector of strings at certain point. It caused me a lot of problems so I decided to extract the problematic part and I can't figure out what seems to be the problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

bool myComp(string a, string b){
    return a<b;
}

int main(){
    
    vector<string> students(50000);

    int i = 0;
    while(true){
        string input;
        getline(cin, students[i]);
        if(!students[i].empty()){
            i++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << students[2] << endl << students[1] << endl;
    sort(students.begin(), students.end());
    cout << students[2] << endl << students[1];

    return 0;
}
```

At first I thought  that input was wrong (problem specifically requests to read until empty line), but it turned out that program works correctly up to moment of sorting. I would be very grateful if anyone was to clear this out for me I am banging my head for more than an hour.

Comment: What is your input and what is your expected output vs. actual output? Also, what purpose does `myComp()` serve? It looks like you never use it.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Note that after sorting the first `50000 - i` strings in the vector will be empty.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue here is that you're making a `vector` with 50000 empty strings and only actually filling 10-20 values. So when you sort, the first 48980 values are going to be empty strings. Is there a reason you're not just starting with an empty vector and using `push_back()`?

Comment: myComp is an example of function I saw on internet regarding this topic. I tried to use it in sorting but even with it, program doesn't work. My expected output is for example: INPUT: John, Anne, Shaun, James, to write out  Anne, James, John, Shaun. In separated lines. After sorting it prints nothing.

Comment: Clarify the "but afterwards it can't do anything" part. Does the program stop? crash? just not output anything with the last `cout`?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include the expected output. If you know you don't use `myComp`, then remove it as well, so that your code becomes a [mcve]. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @BonkoZvogdan try outputting `students[49999]` after sorting

Comment: This would be a great time to learn to use a debugger so that you can inspect the contents of the vector before and after the sort.

Comment: @BonkoZvogdan `sort(students.begin(), students.end());` -- You realize you're sorting everything, including the blank names?  And as the previous comment stated, why are you starting out with a vector of 50000 strings?  What if there were more than 50000 names in the file?  That's why you should either start out with an empty vector and call `push_back`, or write the loop so that you don't exceed the number of items in the vector.

Comment: @scohe001 only reason was because I thought it was the same thing. I tried with `push_back()` and that sealed the deal. At college we currently learn both Java and C++ and I was more concentrated on Java. I am still not completely comfortable with cpp syntax. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When learning C++, pretend Java does not exist.  Do not use Java as a model in writing C++ code, and do not use C++ as a model in writing Java code.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious issue with your code is that you have a vector of 50000 strings. You then try an sort that vector of 50000 strings. It seems obvious that you really want the size of the vector to equal the number of strings input. The easy way to do that is to grow the vector as you input strings. Use the `push_back` method for that.

Here's some code

```
vector<string> students; // initial size of vector is zero

int i = 0;
while(true){
    string input;
    getline(cin, input); // read into the input variable
    if (input.empty())   // break if input is empty
        break;
    students.push_back(input); // add the input to the vector
}
```

Now with the vector sized correctly you should find sorting it to be no problem

```
cout << students[2] << endl << students[1] << endl;
sort(students.begin(), students.end());
cout << students[2] << endl << students[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using incorrect arguments in the call of `std::sort`.

```
sort(students.begin(), students.end());
```

The vector students contains 50000 elements

```
vector<string> students(50000);
```

It seems you mean

```
#include <iterator>

//...

sort(students.begin(), std::next( students.begin(), i ));
```

or

```
sort(students.begin(), std::next( students.begin(), i ), myComp );
```

where `myComp` should be defined at least like

```
bool myComp( const string &a, const string &b){
    return a<b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> students;
   students.reserve(50000);  // want to avoid `students` reallocation for first
                             // 50'000 entries but size is still zero (`0`)
   std::string line;
   // read until end-of-input or empty line
   while(std::getline(std::cin, line) && !line.empty())
      students.push_back(line);  // no reallocation for first 50'000 entries!
   if(students.size() < 3)
   {
      std::cerr << "Need at least three students for example\n";
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   std::cout << students[2] << '\n' << students[1] << '\n';
   std::partial_sort(    // Only pick out three "smallest" strings for example
      students.begin(),  // no need to sort more than necessary with 50'000 :-)
      std::next(students.begin(), 3),
      students.end());
   std::cout << students[2] << '\n' << students[1] << std::endl;
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You have written a comparator function `myComp()` but you haven't used it. I'd suggest using it as the third parameter for `sort()` and see if things get better. i.e.;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

bool myComp(string a, string b){
    return a<b;
}

int main(){
    
    vector<string> students(50000);

    int i = 0;
    while(true){
        string input;
        getline(cin, students[i]);
        if(!students[i].empty()){
            i++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << students[2] << endl << students[1] << endl;
    sort(students.begin(), students.end(), myComp);
    cout << students[2] << endl << students[1];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The comparator `myComp` does exactly the same thing as the default comparator would do.

Comment: We have no idea what OP is expecting the output to be. But I can say with confidence that this will give the same exact output as whatever they have now.

Comment: The difference with `myComp` is the additional cost of taking the parameters by value instead of const reference.